# Allow authors to post only in categories they create in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to allow users with an assigned role in WordPress to create new categories and then automatically be restricted to only posting in those categories or the default 'uncategorized'?

There are plenty of plugins that restrict posting to a certain category, but they all require an admin to set permissions and I need permissions to be assigned automatically upon creation.

Essentially, I'm creating a story-building tool where users can add new 'stories' or 'series' (I have renamed the 'post' and 'category' labels) so they need to be able to create a new 'series' that only they can add to.

Thanks!

Comment: Something like the "Restrict Author Posting" plugin perhaps http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-restrict-authors-specific-category-in-wordpress/  or a thread on the topic with many plugins https://wordpress.org/support/topic/assign-categories-to-users

Comment: Unfortunately, that one also requires the permissions to be set by an admin and most of the ones in that thread haven't been updated in many years. I'm looking for something more than simply restricting authors - I need them to be able to create unlimited new categories and automatically be restricted to the categories they themselves create.

Comment: Don't know if you saw this one -although it is not quite the same, the answer given seems to have possibilities. Each story could then be a post. Perhaps you could restrict access to the  `edit_post_link(` so they could only see it if they were the post's author, but they could probably still get to the url so that might not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082569/each-user-can-edit-only-one-page-wordpress?rq=1

Comment: It looks as though going multisite might also be a way for you to go, where you have a central control panel but many blog sites - for example:  https://www.designwall.com/blog/10-wordpress-multisite-plugins-you-shouldnt-live-without/  and  http://wplift.com/wordpress-multisite-guide

Comment: This explains setting up multisite WordPress well too https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ultimate-guide-multisite/ Perhaps posting this on the WordPress SO might get you more targeted responses  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm hoping not to have to go multisite as I feel there must be a php solution here, but it's an option. I didn't even know there was a WordPress SO, but I will try there - thanks, Steve!

Comment: Best of luck! It does look as though there is not a huge amount of script in the user restrictions plugins so you might get lucky if you can find a WordPress PHP wiz. Maybe worth downloading one and having a look to get some ideas.

Comment: There may be a clue here - each contributor could be a category and all their posts be a subcategory of that, then they could have a page which shows only their main category and subcategories. http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-categories-and-subcategories-to-wordpress/ Still looking to find a way to identify the originator of a category - this is what is in the category array https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category   and how to get at it https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

Comment: Looks like kaiser on this page knows a fair bit about this kind of issue http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13025/how-would-i-increase-the-author-role-to-be-able-to-add-a-new-category

Comment: Probably shouldn't suggest looking at plugins and am not recommending it as such but BuddyPress does have a lot of capacity for management built in https://buddypress.org/

Comment: That's what I've been doing - dissecting plugins to see if I can modify the php. I'm not using BuddyPress, as it's far too much of a bully, overriding theme settings and such. That other thread might do the trick for me - I'll let you know! :)

Comment: This post's answer appears to show a means of adding an attribut to a category, which you could get back - so you could add the current user to the category when it is created and compare that to the username when an attempt is made to access/edit it by a given user http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159873/add-category-attribute-to-custom-recent-post-shortcode and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507816/php-wordpress-add-attribute-to-current-category-in-unordered-list even https://en.bainternet.info/custom-taxonomies-extra-fields/

Comment: Don't know if you are still looking at this but I came across this post which might help https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-only-my-posts-in-the-loop-if-im-a-logged-in-user